# Should a cross platform app on Windows and macOS have different Google OAuth 2.0 client IDs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

For a cross platform app that's on Windows and macOS, should this use the same Google OAuth 2.0 client ID for both platforms, or separate IDs?

The Google docs state that [each platform should have its own client ID](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id), but there's no specific platform selection for Windows and macOS, just "Desktop" - while there are specific platforms for e.g. iOS and Android. This leads me to believe they consider all desktop platforms as one.

Comment: which Google documentation are you referring to? edit your question and provide the url of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider all desktop operating systems as one in this context as they offer the same capabilities w.r.t. how they can use a browser to complete an authorization flow. `gcloud`, for example, also uses the same client ID across all OS.